# directory path seems not working properly after mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I put index.php and .htaccess  under  directory  localhost/domain/us. 
In the .htaccess, I have

```
Options -Indexes 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z_]+)$ index.php [L] 
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z_]+)$ index.php [L]
```

I got index.php correctly when I typed in url  "localhost/domain/us/aaa" . 
But when I typed in  "localhost/domain/us/aaa/bbb", I can get to index.php page but it was messed up. All the css files seems not working and images appeared.

In index.php, I used

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bt.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /> 

<img src="logo/pic.gif" width="50" alt="logo">
```

Both logo and css are folders under  localhost/domain/us . 
Why is the directory path not working properly?

Answer (score 0):

Your css and logo are referenced using relative paths. This means that when you visit the localhost/domain/us/aaa/bbb page the browser will try to download the css and logo from the localhost/domain/us/aaa/css/bt.css and localhost/domain/us/aaa/logo/pic.gif URLs.

So you can either use absolute paths in your references or add new rules to .htaccess to catch the css and logo folders. E.g. for the logo folder:

```
RewriteRule /?(logo/.*)$ $1 [L]
```

Comment: Sometimes, it is more convenient to use relative path. The aaa, and bbb  are very likely dummy files and folders. Therefore it make more sense to refer to the directory where index.php locates in directory path. Is there a way that we can ask apache to do that ?

Comment: You can then use the extra Rule I wrote in the answer. This will match any URL containing logo/<something> and the rewrite it to logo/<something>. Then all requests for content from a folder called logo will be served from the root logo folder. The same can then be done for the css folder. Of course this means that you can not use the names logo or css as aaa or bbb

Comment: The problems are there are many files and directories that I need to refer to using relative path. Writing extra rules seem to be a big burn. Worst of all, I faced some other issue to use root reference.

Comment: If all your "folders" are being handled by the same index.php page, you could make that page use dynamic relative URLs to the resources. When the second rule is matched you need the index.php to add "../" in all the resource URLs. You could tell index.php to do this by adding ?ExtraLevel=1 to the redirect URL for that rule:

RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z_]+)$ index.php?ExtraLevel=1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

Ok so now you've hit the most common problem people face when switching to pretty URL schemes :P Solution is also simple, just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

For your case use this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bt.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /> 

<img src="/logo/pic.gif" width="50" alt="logo">
```